# Symmetry breaking - mixed state in $T\rightarrow 0$ limit

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

In the *quantum*$^1$ system with a continuous symmetry (in the Thermodynamic limit) relating the ground states $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}\{\ket{\theta}\} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|}$ . Before spontaneous symmetry breaking the density operator of is:
$$\rho=e^{-\beta \hat H}$$
After spontaneous symmetry only a subset of states in this operator. In the $T\rightarrow 0$ limit only those states with the ground state energy survive.

My question is the following:

At $T=0$ do we always have:
$$\rho=\ket{\theta_1}\bra{\theta_1}\tag{1}$$

Could we have e.g.
$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\ket{\theta_1}\bra{\theta_1}+\frac{1}{2} \ket{\theta_2}\bra{\theta_2}\tag{2}$$
or more realistically:
$$\rho=\mathcal{N}\int^{\theta_1+\Delta \theta}_{\theta_1-\Delta \theta}d\theta \ket{\theta} \bra{\theta}\tag{3}$$
please can someone explain why which are the possible density operators after SSB in the $T\rightarrow 0$ limit and why.

(I feel we get something like (3) with the Heisenberg model)

<sub>$^1$ although an answer explaining what is different in the classical system would also be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: See: [arxiv:1703.10439](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10439.pdf), [Ellis, 2007; pg92](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Pg_pBwAAQBAJ&dq=convex+sum+of+symmetry+breaking+gibbs+states&source=gbs_navlinks_s) and [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/392649/spontanous-symmetry-breaking-in-the-heisenberg-model) on PSE

Comment: Spontaneous symmetry breaking only occurs in the thermodynamic limit.  However, there it is not clear what the density operator really should be.  From a hand-wavy point of view, I would say that $\rho=|\theta\rangle\langle\theta|$ for any ground state $|\theta\rangle$ (in the tdyn. limit) is the "correct" symmetry broken state.