# Asymptotic behavior of correlations at and away from phase transition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, field-theory, phase-transition

In the following, I am considering lattice systems in statistical mechanics. There are some concepts which are supposed to be related, but I am confused about.

**First:** Correlation length and mass. Correlations in a lattice system is defined by:
$$C(x,y) = \langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle - \langle \phi(x)\rangle\langle \phi(y)\rangle \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Because we can usually redefine the underlying Gaussian measure so that the average of the spins are zero, we can reduce the latter to:
$$C(x,y) = \langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle \tag{2}\label{2}$$

[On this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/671300/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-correlation-length), the author of the most upvoted answer says that, typically, we have:
$$C(x,y) \sim \frac{e^{-|x-y|/\xi}}{|x-y|^{a}} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
where $\xi$ is the correlation length. However, I have seen in other places [e.g. this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526681/argument-for-exponential-decay-of-correlation-function) where this decay is said to be:
$$C(x,y) \sim e^{-|x-y|/\xi} \tag{4}\label{4}.$$
So, why are these different and what is the real decay?

**Second:** It is also said that, at criticality, the correlation length $\xi \to \infty$ so the correlations have a power law decay:
$$C(x,y) \sim |x-y|^{-a}. \tag{5}\label{5}$$
If (\ref{5}) holds, then the latter is invariant under scale, that is, if we rescale $\varphi(x) = L^{-\frac{a}{2}}\phi(x/L)$, then the associated correlation $C(x,y) = C_{L}(x,y)$ of the new fields $\varphi$ satisfy:
$$C_{L}(x,y) = L^{a}|Lx-Ly|^{-a} = |x-y|^{-a} = C(x,y). \tag{6}\label{6}$$
However, as far as I understand, the converse should also be true: if I have a lattice system with scale invariance, then it should be at its critical point. But then, how does scale invariance could imply (\ref{6})? Are these two concepts not equivalent, or is (\ref{6}) a bad definition of phase transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll only answer the first part of your question.

Away from a critical point, the typical decay of the (truncated) 2-point function in lattice systems follows the **Ornstein-Zernike asymptotics**: as $\|y-x\|\to\infty$,
$$
\langle \phi(x);\phi(y) \rangle = \frac{C(n_{y-x})}{\|y-x\|^{(d-1)/2}} e^{-\nu(n_{y-x})\|y-x\|}\, (1+o(1)),
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm and $n_{y-x}=(y-x)/\|y-x\|$. The function $C$ and the mass $\nu$ are anisotropic, but analytic, strictly positive functions of the direction.
The above has been proved rigorously in many models in perturbative regimes, as well as non-perturbatively in simple systems (for instance, the Ising or Potts models in any dimension above the critical temperature, or the Ising model in any dimension in the presence of a nonzero magnetic field).

The behavior stated above is for "ferromagnetic" systems. For more general systems, there is usually an oscillatory term in the prefactor.

Note that Ornstein-Zernike behavior occurs very often, but not *always*. For instance, in the planar Ising model below the critical temperature, it is known that the power in the prefactor is $2$ rather than the usual $1/2$. This is a pathology related to planarity.

More importantly, the range of the interaction plays a crucial role. Namely, if you consider, for instance, a ferromagnetic Ising model with a formal Hamiltonian
$$
\mathcal{H} = -\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z^d}} J_{y-x} \sigma_x\sigma_y,
$$
then:

- Ornstein-Zernike behavior applies when the coupling constants $J_z$ decay faster than any exponential of $\|z\|$ (that is, $\lim_{\|z\|\to\infty}\frac{1}{\|z\|}\log J_z = -\infty$).
- When $J_z$ decays slower than any exponential of $\|z\|$ (that is, $\lim_{\|z\|\to\infty}\frac{1}{\|z\|}\log J_z = 0$), the behavior is different, namely one can prove that, for all $\beta<\beta_c$, as $\|y-x\|\to\infty$,
  $$
  \langle \sigma_x\sigma_y \rangle = \beta\chi^2 J_{y-x}\, (1+o(1)),
  $$
  where $\chi$ is the magnetic susceptibility.
- When $J_z$ decay exponentially with $\|z\|$ (that is, $-\infty < \lim_{\|z\|\to\infty}\frac{1}{\|z\|}\log J_z < 0$), it is the behavior of the sub-exponential prefactor to the exponential decay of $J_z$ that will determine which of the asymptotic behaviors is relevant. There is a known "if and only if" criterion, but it is a bit too complicated to state here.

Finally, the above is for the spin-spin correlations. The behavior of other correlations can be more complicated. For instance, for the finite-range Ising model above the critical temperature, the "energy-energy" correlations behave like
$$
\langle \sigma_a\sigma_b;\sigma_{x+a}\sigma_{x+b} \rangle \sim \frac{1}{\psi(\|x\|)} e^{-2\nu(n_x)\|x\|},
$$
(for fixed $a,b\in\mathbb{Z^d}$) as $\|x\|\to\infty$, where
$$
\Psi(r) = 
\begin{cases}
r^2 & \text{if }d=2,\\
(r\log r)^2 & \text{if }d=3\\
r^{d-1} & \text{if }d\geq 4.
\end{cases}
$$
[This rather recent survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.06207) presents a panorama of some of the known (mathematically rigorous) results for the Ising  model. You can also have a look at this [older paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321385902767), which includes a brief review of the phenomenology for a larger class of models.

---

Some additions, answering your further questions in the comments.

> [T]he authors define the mass (or inverse correlation length) by $m=\xi−1=\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{1}{|x|}\log\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle$, which basically tells us that $\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle \sim e^{−|x−y|/\xi}$.

Notice that if $\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle \sim f(|x-y|)e^{-|x-y|/\xi}$ with $f$ sub-exponential (say, $f(r)=r^{-(d-1)/2}$, for instance), then
$$
\lim_{|x-y|\to\infty} \frac{1}{|x-y|}\log \bigl(f(|x-y|)e^{-|x-y|/\xi}\bigr) = - \frac{1}{\xi} + \lim_{|x-y|\to\infty} \frac{\log f(|x-y|)}{|x-y|} = -\frac{1}{\xi},
$$
so this is perfectly compatible with what the authors state.

> In particular, taking the latter definition, if $\xi\to\infty$ at criticality, then $\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle \sim 1$, not $|x−y|^{−a}$. It seems inconsistent to the critical behavior.

Apart from the confusion already discussed just above, there is another important problem. The asymptotic behavior described in the first part of my answer (in particular the OZ asymptotics) are long-distance phenomena. In particular, they only apply when $|x-y| \gg \xi$. When approaching criticality, the correlation length $\xi$ diverges and (often) the relevant behavior is between spins located at vertices such that $|x-y| \ll \xi$. The exponents governing the latter are different from the exponents in the prefactor to the exponential decay when $|x-y|\gg\xi$. This is in particular true at the critical point, since $\xi=\infty$ in that case. (For instance, the planar Ising model for any $\beta<\beta_c$ has $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_x\rangle_\beta \sim |x|^{-1/2} e^{-\nu_\beta(n_x)|x|}$ (when $|x|$ is much larger than the correlation length), while $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_x\rangle_{\beta_c} \sim |x|^{-1/4}$.)

In order to understand better how these various regimes follow from a common asymptotic behavior, I strongly recommend to have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.04717). The latter provides detailed computations in the simpler case of the lattice Green function. In particular, they obtain a formula for the correlation valid *in all regimes*. One can then see how this general behaviors crosses to OZ behavior when the distance is large compared to the correlation length, and to a power law decay far below the correlation length (in particular, at the critical point).

Comment: Yvan, thanks for your answer. I am confused. Consider this paper: http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1981-1982__24__159_0.pdf
which also provides a panorama of mathematically rigorous results. On page 11, item (e), the authors define the mass (or inverse correlation length) by $m = \xi^{-1} = \lim_{|x|\to \infty}\frac{1}{|x|}\ln\langle \varphi(x)\varphi(y)\rangle$, which basically tells us that $\langle \varphi(x)\varphi(y)\rangle \sim e^{-|x-y|/\xi}$. According to your answer (and some posts linked in the question), a factor $|x-y|^{-a}$ is missing. I don't know why.

Comment: In particular, taking the latter definition, if $\xi \to \infty$ at criticality, then $\langle \varphi(x)\varphi(y)\rangle \sim 1$, not $|x-y|^{-a}$. It seems inconsistent to the critical behavior. What am I missing?

Comment: Just notice that any subexponential prefactor to the exponential decay of the 2-point function dispappears in the limit you quote (once you take the logarithm, the prefactor becomes a logarithmic quantity, which, once divided by $\|x\|$ vanishes in the limit $\|x\|\to\infty$...).

Comment: Moreover, the exponent you see in the prefactor at $\beta<\beta_c$ does not become the exponent of the algebraic decay at criticality. The point is that OZ-type behavior is a long-distance phenomenon, and in particular only holds far beyond the correlation length. When $\beta\to\beta_c$, the correlation length diverges and what you see is the correlation for spins at a distance much smaller than the correlation length. The latter is governed by different exponents.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this old paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321385902767), one of whose authors co-authored the review you cite. They are clearly stating exactly the same thing as I do (of course, the results they quote are all perturbative, because one could not do better at that time).

Comment: I've included more detailed versions of my comments above in my post. Hopefully this will help clarify the problems.

Comment: Yvan, now things became really more clear. I have to thank you again. In short, because of the logarithm both expressions (with the prefactor and without it) are equivalent, and the asymptotics $e^{-|x-y|/\xi}/|x-y|^{a}$ describes a system close to criticality. Is that right?

Comment: Yes for the first part. For the second part, be careful that $e^{-|x-y|/\xi}/|x-y|^a$ is the form of the correlation function when $|x-y|$ is much larger than the correlation length. Far below the correlation length, the exponential decay becomes negligible and the decay is (usually) a power law, but the exponent is in general **not the same** as the exponent $a$ appearing in the prefactor obtained when considering $|x-y|$ larger than the correlation length. See the example of the 2d Ising model at the end of my answer.

Comment: The reason for this can be understood in a very nice way when considering the case of the lattice Green function, for which highly detailed explicit computations are feasible. See Theorem 1.3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.04717.pdf).

Comment: Yvan, I still want to address these last points you raised, but maybe it is a good practice not to extend the discussion in the comments. I will send you a message in the chat, if this is okay with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150447/discussion-between-mathmath-and-yvan-velenik).